# Sudden consumption of all connections in pool (node-postgres)

Tags: node-postgres

I am experiencing problems with DB access using node-posgres module to execute multiple almost simultaneous DB queries. One of the following two errors happen:

"timeout exceeded when trying to connect" (more often)
"sorry, too many clients already" (when I increase max connections)

What I find strange is that the number of connections in pool immediately jumps to max 20 (see configuration below), with 0 idle.

If I increase max to 200, similar thing happens - it jumps to 200. I suspect my configuration is not correct.

Any ideas?

Here is my configuration:

```
{
                host: this.PG_HOST,
                port: this.PG_PORT,
                user: this.PG_USER,
                password: this.PG_PASS,
                database: this.PG_DB,
                max: 20, // max number of clients in the pool
                // number of milliseconds a client must sit idle in the pool and not be checked out
                // before it is disconnected from the backend and discarded
                // default is 10000 (10 seconds) - set to 0 to disable auto-disconnection of idle clients
                idleTimeoutMillis: 10000,
                // number of milliseconds to wait before timing out when connecting a new client
                // by default this is 0 which means no timeout
                connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
            };
```